# Cannot delete manifest file

Tags: autodesk-forge

I tried to delete manifest file, but can't. Any help? I'm coding in Ruby.

```
access_token = AutodeskForge.get_access_token(oauth_scope:'data:write data:read')
response = RestClient.delete(
  "#{API_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/#{base_64_urn}/manifest",
  { Authorization: "Bearer #{access_token}" }
)
```

=> "404 Not Found"

"x-ads-troubleshooting"=>["Fail to authorize the input urn. Either the object doesn't exist or you don't have permission to view the object."]

However, I can get detail of a manifest

```
response = HTTParty.get("#{API_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/#{urn}/manifest", headers: headers)
```

=> Get the manifest detail

I read this ducoment.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/
As it is written, I set "data:write data:read" in scope

this is a function to get access_token

```
  def self.get_access_token(oauth_scope:)
    options = {
      body: { 
        client_id: Rails.application.credentials.autodesk[:forge][:client_id],
        client_secret: Rails.application.credentials.autodesk[:forge][:client_secret],
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: oauth_scope
      }
    }
    response = HTTParty.post("#{API_URL}/authentication/v1/authenticate", options)
    JSON.parse(response.body)['access_token']
  end
```

Comment: Did you try to delete manifest by tools like Postman? Is it still not working? If it doesn't work either, it might be related to the URN you passed to the DELETE endpoint. Try to remove `=` in the URN, then retry.

Comment: I tried the delete process using curl. ```curl -X DELETE -H "Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}" -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest"``` and the same result. ```x-ads-troubleshooting: Fail to authorize the input urn. Either the object doesn't exist or you don't have permission to view the object.``` Can you try this delete process on your side? Can you delete manifest?

Comment: I can't see any '=' in urn which is Base64 encoded urn.

Comment: Get manifest request works out. ```curl -X 'GET' -H 'Authorization: Bearer {access_token}' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/{urn}/manifest'```

Comment: I'm wondering if oauth scope is not correct. To delete manifest, only 'data:read data:write' is required right?

Comment: The required scopes are `data:read data:write` without doubts. You may test with Postman or other REST API clients. Or decode your access tokens with https://jwt.io/ to see if they contain correct scopes.

Answer (score 0):

This scope works out.

```
data:write data:read viewables:read
```

document is incorrect.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE/

Comment: No... I can delete the manifest with `data:read data:write` scopes.